# How to convert a block of rendered HTML code or a div into a PNG?

Tags: html, canvas

A few notes: 
a) not an entire page, 
b) not from server side.  
c) rendered or "treated" HTML, for instance, 

`<table>
<tr><td width="5%"> <td>fact 1 </td>  fact 2 </td> </tr>
</table>`

desired results (for the PNG):

```
  fact 1    fact 2

fact 3    fact 4  
...
```

not
fact 1 fact 2
fact 3 fact 4
...

The <code> "sign"nbsp; </code> may be used to create white space but again it needs to be rendered.

Probably some javascript that first acts a ua (browser) to get the rendered data first and 
then transforms it into a bmp format that PNG supports... how?  code sample would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you wish to do this? You say you primarily need Firefox support, so I'm just trying to understand the purpose as a good alternative/workaround might be possible - what's the PNG to be used for?

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with generating it server-side?

*EDIT:* What's wrong with just using html+css? For the user it looks the same, prints the same AND it's faster, searchable and accessible AND you can easily manipulate it with Javascript. I fail to see why you would want to have the images in the first place.

This question's short answer is the same as from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276598/how-to-load-a-html-file-into-canvas/3276604#3276604): **No, you cannot.**
There are many problems you have to overcome, including but not limited to:

- You would need to correctly render HTML into a bitmap. This is infinitely more difficult than it seems.
- Compressing an image using PNG is not trivial, and while it's technically possible to do that with JS, it's definitely a very bad idea.

Even if you somehow manage to get around these problems, you will end up with hacky and extremely brittle code that have nearly no chance of working cross-browser.

> Doing this would be like needing some
>   concrete and developing a Moon rocket
>   to harvest lunar dust to make it
>   instead of buying some at Home Depot.

*- ceejayoz,* on a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263694/how-to-convert-png-to-gif-using-javascript-or-other-client-side-tech/1263721#1263721) topic

There are however [alternatives](http://softwareas.com/ajaxjavascript-8-ways-to-create-graphics-on-the-fly) (SVG, Canvas, server-side generation, ...) you might want to look at.

---

*EDIT 2:* [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DbEuC/) of images loaded directly from the HTML file

I used PHP to base64_encode those images. Here's the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var imgs = [];
<?php

$imgArray = array('angry.gif', 'pray.gif', 'think.gif');
$imgs = array_map(function ($d) {return base64_encode(file_get_contents($d));}, $imgArray);
$i=0;

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo 'imgs[' . $i++ . '] = "' . $img . "\";\n";
}
?>

function changeImg() {
    i = (i+1) % imgs.length;
    var img = document.getElementById('theImage');
    img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + imgs[i];
}
</script>
<body onload="changeImg()">
<input type="button" onclick="changeImg();" value="Change Image" /><br /><br />
<img src="" id="theImage" alt="" />
```

Comment: Well, currently, the server side: I'm using Railo, sort of equivalent to Adobe's ColdFusion for it, at the moment, it is unable to do it.

So, it looks like I'm stuck.

Comment: Aircule, this PNG image would serve as a base... ahe, just learn you work for google... and the pic is funny, funny and smart dude :)

Comment: "

    Doing this would be like needing some concrete and developing a Moon rocket to harvest lunar dust to make it instead of buying some at Home Depot.

- ceejayoz,"

That is ABSOLUTELY NOT TRUE for my case.

Comment: @Aircule,

I attempted to the #7 of "Create an image and set its src to a data: resource" but failed with Firefox and (the app is not a public/hosted service, so we have some degree of "control"/recommendation of browser.   Also, attempt to load a SVG into canvas failed too.  Very discouraging.

Comment: @Don Don If you do #7, you need to encode your binary data in a way that you can serve with HTML files (ie: base64). See this [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/DbEuC/)

Comment: @Aircule, sorry I think you misunderstood my question.
In essence, it's like this:
a) do stuff, output to a var (data are simple HTML elements and smallish, less than 150 characters)
b) convert/export the above var to png or gif images, if can't fine.
c) use HTML5 canvas to retrieve the data.

Also, I can't use php code.  I appreciate your effort tho.