# How to load a HTML file into canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I know we can load an image into a canvas but I wonder if we are able to load a simple HTML file into a canvas.  If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: What canvas? What language are you using?

Comment: In order to get an answer try to add more information. For example programming language...

Comment: @Mewp @AdrianFaciu It's 99% likely that he's talking about HTML5 canvas, with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

> Short answer: No, you cannot.

**Long answer:**
Not reliably, BUT yes you can in certain (possibly hackish) ways. The key is in what you define as an "image". You are aware that you can add an image to the canvas with `drawImage()` - what you mightn't be aware of is what that "image" can be (not necessarily an actual image).

Firstly, the "image" can be a HTML5 video element - so you can add videos to the canvas.
Secondly, in most modern browsers the "image" can be an SVG document, which can contain HTML via the SVG `<foreignObject>` element.

**Browser support:**

- SVG documents in `drawImage()` are not currently supported in Firefox. The [related bug is here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276431) and I think a fix is planned.
- `<foreignObject>` is buggy in most browsers - Firefox (ironically) seems to have the best support.

**Example:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <foreignObject x="0" y="0" height="800" width="800">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <p>Hello world!</p>
   <input type="date"/>
  </body>
 </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Try loading that file with canvas `drawImage()` in Opera - as you'll see its interactivity is fairly buggy, but it displays fine.

Comment: // browser = Firefox v3.66; os = crappy Vista 
// and we must support FF  
var canvas= document.getElementById('oneElement'); 
var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');
var img= new Image();
 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
 }
  
 img.src = 'element1.html'; 

// outcome 
the html file has not been loaded into the canvas

Comment: Hey Don Don - as I said in the first line of the answer "Not reliably" - I wouldn't recommend doing this in any production sites yet, just informing you of the possibility.

Comment: ok.

Could you take a look at another related question??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276131/how-to-convert-a-block-of-rendered-html-code-or-a-div-into-a-png

Thanks.

Don

Answer (score 1):

He's talking about HTML5 / Javascript.

It's not possible without writing your own Rendering Engine (in Javascript).

Comment: @Mewp,
HTNL and javascript and HTML5 canvas.

Answer (score 1):

[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) or [rasterizeHTML.js](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) seem the tools you are looking for.

A third solution without plugins is presented by Mozilla, but I could not get it running here: [Although it's not trivial (for security reasons), it's possible to draw DOM content—such as HTML—into a canvas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

There is also [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which supports [Screen Capturing](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture)